# Integration of a Jupyter Notebook to Beamer

Tags: listings

For my teaching efforts, I want to integrate some Jupyter-Notebooks to my Presentation, which is written in LaTeX. These Notebooks contain examples and assignments. And these examples/assignments I want to structure dynamically, meaning that I can change my files without much hassle, either for different or new topics. I know that the `\listings` command makes it possible, to add `.py` files (and for that fact any other supported programming language) into LaTeX and hence make a frame. But is this also possible for `.ipynb` files?

Ive added a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\definecolor{codegreen}{RGB}{17,136,17}
\definecolor{codegray}{RGB}{14,14,14}
\definecolor{codered}{RGB}{173,46,46}
\definecolor{codeblue}{RGB}{16,16,255}

\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    basicstyle=\small\firamonolining,
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{codegreen},
    identifierstyle=\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codered},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    captionpos=b,
}
\lstset{style=codestyle}

\lstdefinelanguage{Py}[]{Python}{
    morekeywords=[1]{,as,assert,nonlocal,with,yield,self,True,False,None,} 
}

\lstset{literate=%
  {Ö}{{\"O}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1
  {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1
  {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}


\subsection{Manual Integration of Code}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Py]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
y=np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
print ("Hello World")
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy.functions import *
from sympy import *
f=sin(x/(2*pi))
plot(f,diff(f), size=(3,3))
def polar(x,y):
    if x<=0 or y<=0:
        print('N')
    else:
        r=sqrt(x**2+y**2)
        phi=asin(y/r)
        return(r,(phi*180/pi)
  \end{lstlisting}

\subsection[fragile]{Automated Integration of Code via listing and .py-file}
\lstinputlisting[langauge=Py,firstline=1,lastline=22]{Test.py}

============


**%\lstinputlisting[language=Py, firstline=1,lastline=22]{Test.ipynb}**

=========

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

The line in question is: **%\lstinputlisting[language=Py, firstline=1,lastline=22]{Test.ipynb}**

Is it possible to add a .ipynb-file (either via the listing command or a completely different one) to my LaTeX-PDF, without manually adding it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Ive tried to get it to work through your suggestion yesterday but it either breaks my beamer or just doesnt show up on a frame.

Comment: In that case, you should show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).